# Button is not working in odoo 10 community

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-view

I have added three extra fields to `project.task` model: 
Now I need to add a button to task form view to see parent task or subtasks.
The button does not appear.

model:

```py
parent_id = fields.Many2one('project.task', string='Parent Task')
child_ids = fields.One2many('project.task', 'parent_id', string="Sub-tasks")
subtask_count = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_subtask_count', type='integer', string="Sub-task count")
```

code for the button:

```py
@api.multi
def _compute_subtask_count(self):
    for task in self:
        task.subtask_count = self.search_count([('id', 'child_of', task.id), ('id', '!=', task.id)])

def action_open_parent_task(self):
    return {
        'name': _('Parent Task'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'project.task',
        'res_id': self.parent_id.id,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'
    }
```

view.xml

```xml
<button class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-tasks" type="object" name="action_open_parent_task" string="Parent Task" attrs="{'invisible' : [('parent_id', '=', False)]}" groups="project.group_subtask_project"/>
            <button name="500" type="action" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-tasks" attrs="{'invisible' : [('parent_id', '!=', False)]}" context="{'project_id': subtask_project_id, 'name': name, 'partner_id': partner_id}" groups="project.group_subtask_project">
                <field string="Sub-tasks" name="subtask_count" widget="statinfo"/>
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will not work, function name should be button name

Answer (score 0):

You have created "**action**" button. So for that name of the button is "**action_open_parent_task**" insted of "**500"**.

And you have to write name in xml like this:

```
            <button name="%(action_open_parent_task)d" type="action" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-tasks" attrs="{'invisible' : [('parent_id', '!=', False)]}" context="{'project_id': subtask_project_id, 'name': name, 'partner_id': partner_id}" groups="project.group_subtask_project">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button code is not seems like its working. Wrong implementation.

Answer (score 0):

XML Button view:

```
<div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box" groups="project.group_subtask_project"/>
    <button name="action_open_parent_task" type="object" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-tasks" attrs="{'invisible' : [('parent_id', '!=', False)]}" context="{'project_id': subtask_project_id, 'name': name, 'partner_id': partner_id}">
        <field string="Sub-tasks" name="subtask_count" widget="statinfo"/>
    </button>
</div
```